# Copying DB from bundle to Documents directory during applicationdidfinishlaunch

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my application launches, I check if a DB exists in the Documents directory.  If it doesn't then I want to copy the DB I have in the main bundle to the Documents directory for the app.

Seems pretty straightforward, however I am getting a cocoa error code 4 ONLY when I run my code in the simulator.  The cocoa error code means that a file does not exist.  I've narrowed it down to it most likely being that the Documents directory does not exist at this point in the code.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.db"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath]) {
    //PERFORM DATA MIGRATIONS IF ANY EXIST
}
else {
    NSString *appDBBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"app" ofType:@"db"];
    NSError *error;
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:appDBBundlePath toPath:appDBPath error:&error]) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

I always thought the Documents directory would exist once the app was installed.  What am I doing wrong?  Note: I am able to copy the DB from bundle to Documents directory with the app on a physical device.

Comment: What happens when you get a reference to the documents directory by doing `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]`?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't given the simulator the proper file system permissions.

Comment: Try by getting documents directory like this:
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested before Muhammad and I still get the issue.